# The server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), ERR_FAILED.Unchecked runtime.lastError

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

The errors appear at the console after i open this code on live server on vscode, im learning Vue.js and the code itself opens the file but i dont know how to fix those errors.

Ive reasearched somethings about the errors  but couldnt fix them.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="./vuejs"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>teste</p>
    <script>
        const vm = new Vue();
        console.log(vm)

    </script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Hey, try removing the `<script src="./vuejs"></script>` from the list of scripts

Comment: i did this at the same errors remain